# Is Python Xarray giving opposite filter results?

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have an NC file filled with `Temperature (K)`. I am trying to limit the maximum to **260K**. When using `T.where(T>260,260)`, nothing changes. However, it works with `T.where(T<260,260)`. Why is this method so counterintuitive?

```
T.where(T<260,260)    
array([252.14595, 252.14595, 252.14595, ..., 260.  , 260.  ,260.  ])
```

Tried both `> and <`, only to find that the logically opposite mark works. So I can not figure out the logic of this.

Comment: It looks like you’re interpreting “`.where`” narratively as *replace where* but the interpretation is actually *retain where*. I agree that alone, the interpretation is ambiguous, but xarray borrows the behavior from [pandas](//pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) and [numpy](//numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) which have the same function with the same interpretation. The function matching your description is called [mask](//pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) in pandas, but xarray does not have this function.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is working exactly as intuitively expected.

Your example `T.where(T<260,260)` gives you the values of T, where T < 260, and the value of the second argument 260 where T is => 260.

This is similar to how other numerical frameworks with boolean indexing works.

`T.where(T>260,260)` should give you the values of T where T > 260, and the second argument (default value) of 260 where T<=260

If you're having problems with the second example, then I wonder if you are sure that your sample data has any values larger than 260?

According to the [docs](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.where.html);

> xarray.DataArray.where(***cond***, ***other***=, drop=False)

And just like Michael states in the comment, the ***cond*** argument is “Locations at which to preserve this object’s values;”, while ***other*** is “Value to use for locations in this object where ***cond*** is False.“

Also take care to look at the docs for the correct function, as it is easy to confuse it with

> xarray.where(***cond***, ***x***, ***y***, keep_attrs=None)

which has a different logic of ***x*** where ***cond***, else **y**

Comment: Your interpretation is exactly right, but the correct docs reference is for [`xr.DataArray.where`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.where.html) - the cond argument is “Locations at which to preserve this object’s values;” other is “Value to use for locations in this object where cond is False.“ you’re looking at the docs for the module-level function `xr.where`, which has a different signature.

Comment: Yes, I updated the answer at the same time as you posted your question, about exactly the fact that the docs doesn't really explain what happens when where is called with only cond, x,  and not cond,x,y

Comment: No - you’re looking at the wrong part of the docs. The docs are correct and clear (in my opinion) if you’re referencing the correct DataArray method call.

Comment: You are right I was looking at xarray.where, not xr.DataArray.where  , and I agree the docs are correct and makes total sense. I will update (again)

Comment: Thanks so much! The confusing bit is the presence of the two functions so you’re not the only one who’s mixed those up :) really appreciate you following through, and answering the question!